# Python: Open() using a variable

Tags: python, string-formatting

I've run into a problem when opening a file with a randomly generated name in Python 2.6.

```
import random

random = random.randint(1,10)

localfile = file("%s","wb") % random
```

Then I get an error message about the last line:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'file' and 'int'
```

I just can't figure this out by myself, nor with Google, but there has to be a cure for this, I believe.

Comment: Your basic understanding is wrong. I think you need to review the Python tutorials.

Comment: Sorry for that, I've just gotten started with Python

Comment: You don't say what you want the file for, but it looks like you need `tempfile` instead. Look it up in the docs for the standard library.

Comment: Tempfile module doesn't suit the needs actually, the script is for downloading the same image every other second (it's a webcam stream)

Answer (score 9):

This will probably work:

```
import random

num = random.randint(1, 10)
localfile = open("%d" % num, "wb")
```

Note that I've changed a couple of things here:

1. You shouldn't assign the generated random number to a variable named `random` as you are overwriting the existing reference to the module `random`. In other words, you will not be able to access `random.randint` any more if you overwrite `random` with the randomly generated number.
2. The formatting operator (`%`) should be applied to the string you are formatting, not the call to the `file` method.
3. I guess `file` is deprecated in Python 3. It's time to get used to using `open` instead of `file`.
4. Since you are formatting an integer into a string, you should write `"%d"` instead of `"%s"` (although the latter would work as well).

An alternative way of writing `"%d" % num` is `str(num)`, which might be a bit more efficient.

Comment: Thank you! The "%d" % num method works fine.
But I can't figure out how to use either str(num) or int(num) in the same case, it seems to be quite hard to move from PHP to Python.

Comment: You can use `str()` by doing `open(str(num), 'wb')`, `int()` won't work in this case since `open` expects the first parameter to be a `string`, also it` wouldn't do that much, since `num` is already an `integer`.

Comment: Must have been my mistake it didn't work last time, but thank you very much for your reply!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
localfile = file("%s" % random,"wb")
```